# What specific subgenre is the music of Siamés?

Tags: identify-this-genre

What specific subgenre is this band?

That's a question frequently asked. I heard many different opinions, but none expert.

Some said new wave, others said funk pop. Other say "indie", but indie is too general. It can mean anything.

The band's name is Siamés. Here is a [list of his most known hits](https://www.youtube.com/user/SIAMESTV/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid).

Comment: It's entirely possible for a band to be new wave, funk pop, *and* indie at the same time. Or maybe at different times, on different songs - because as you rightly point out in your question, different genre labels focus on different aspects of the band or music.

Comment: @topo Reinstate Monica Ok, but what genre are the songs of that band? Let's say "the wolf", or "as you get high"

Comment: There are rock elements and there are synth pop elements, so I'd personally just say something very general like "alternative rock" or "pop rock". But other people might have other opinions - there's no definitive answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **contemporary indie-dance-pop**. It has some influences from EDM, and from older dance styles such as disco and funk, but it's light and pop oriented. At the same time, it's much more beat-oriented than indie-pop. It's not quite commercial and mainstream enough to be just dance-pop, and it's definitely contemporary, it has a very 20-teens sound.

That's a hybrid subgenre, but it's the only way to get as specific as you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"Alternative" or "indie" is my best guess. However, I don't listen to them, so I may not be the best expert. However, after doing some research, it seems that they fall under those two genres.

Comment: Indie is not a genre. It just means independent. Independent of a music seal.

Answer (score 0):

I would say their genre is made up of multiple genres. I take it to be a mix of EDM, pop, and rock with influence from funk.